# Possible and then how to install Neo4j with headless java on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: java, neo4j, ubuntu-14.04, deb, headless

I'm installing Neo4j on a headless system, a virtual server only accessible by ssh. When using the instructions from http://debian.neo4j.org/, the package manager wishes to install java-runtime, which pulls in all kinds of GUI-related packages. There is a headless version available (java-runtime-headless), but it is clear that this doesn't satisfy the dependency.

Is it possible to install Neo4j, using the deb repository made available, with the headless java runtime and then how, or are some of the non-headless packages really required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I created a dummy package that makes `java7-runtime-headless` satisfy `java7-runtime` using the `equivs` package. See the question “[How to fake a package version installed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18192)” for general information.

The package file I wrote is as simple as

```
Section: java
Priority: optional
Standards-Version: 3.9.2

Package: java7-runtime-dummy4headless
Maintainer: equaeghe <equaeghe@example.com>
Depends: java7-runtime-headless
Provides: java7-runtime
Description: fake package to allow us to use java7-runtime-headless instead of java7-runtime for neo4j
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Oracle JDK - doesn't depend on any gui related packages (it probably does for some tools, but not explicitly).

Full JDK (java development kit) might come in handy when you start debugging some issues.

Here is how to install oracle jdk:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html

Comment: Personally, I would like to keep external dependencies to a minimum, so this option is less attractive.

Comment: Thanks, you saved my day !